# Angular Select ng-model doesnt bind to scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following form:

```
    <form role="form" class="form-validation" ng-submit="profilCtrl.saveProfile()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Fornavn</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="John Hansen" class="form-control" ng-model="profile.firstname" name="name" value="{{profilCtrl.profile.firstname}}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Efternavn</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="John Hansen" class="form-control" ng-model="profile.lastname" name="name" value="{{profilCtrl.profile.lastname}}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Addresse</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Mosebakken 12 2830 virum" class="form-control" ng-model="profile.address" name="address" value="{{profilCtrl.profile.address}}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Jobprofil</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedTitle" ng-options="item as item.name for item in titles"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Telefon Number</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="12345678" class="form-control" name="phone" value="{{profilCtrl.profile.phone}}" required ng-model="profile.phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Afdeling</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDivision" ng-options="division as division.name for division in divisions" required>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Fødselsdag</label>
        <input type="text"  placeholder="04-04-1989" class="form-control" name="cpr" ng-model="profile.cpr" value="{{profilCtrl.profile.cpr}}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Vigtig information</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Dette er vigtigt for min leder at vide!" name="info" ng-model="profile.description">{{profile.description}}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="margiv-top-10">
        <button type="submit" href="#" class="btn green-haze">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Everything in this form works expect the two selects:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedTitle" ng-options="item as item.name for item in titles"></select>
```

And:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDivision" ng-options="division as division.name for division in divisions" required>
```

Unlike the others are these not linked to the `profile` object and should instead be saved in `$scope.selectedTitle` and `$scope.selectedDivision`

However once i submit the form both of these are undefined.

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening

Comment: you should always have a dot in ng-model...  mostly you are facing, the dot problem of angular

Comment: Hey @Marc, it seems you are using "ControllerAs" syntax. How are you accessing to those selectedDivision variables in the controller? You will not get them by `this.selectedDivision` or `vm.selectedDivision` etc.